# is it possible to mount a host directory as a volume on a running docker container?

Tags: mount, docker

I only found instructions on how to run a container and mount a volume at the same time:

```
$ sudo docker run -d -P --name web -v /src/webapp:/opt/webapp training/webapp python app.py
```

Taken from the [user guide.](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/)

But I don't know the command to run once the container is running.

Comment: Why would you need this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible with the current version of docker. All volumes, links, networking, etc. need to be configured when the container starts.

Follow this [docker pull request](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/8484) for when this functionality may end up being merged.

Comment: I'm not sure this feature will actually fit the author's need. This is more like an implementation of [centralized volume management](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/8363) than volume hotplug/unplug.

Comment: Just a nitpick: networking can be configured on running containers (e.g. attaching a running container to a network you just created)