# Docker mount command (mount failed: Unknown error -1)

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to migrate my existing application to Docker, it mounts an image but is getting an error:

```
 mount failed: Unknown error -1
```

These are the steps:

1. Create an empty floppy image of 1.44 MB as root:

   $ /sbin/mkfs.msdos -C / 1440
2. Mount the directory:

   $ sudo mount -o loop /path/imagefile.img /media/floppy1/
3. Copy the XML file to the mounted directory:

   $ cp file.xml /media/floppy1
4. Unmount the directory:

   $ umount /media/floppy1

I installed utilities to run mkfs.msdos, when I run **mount** command I get the following error:

```
[2016-05-03 05:49:53,631: DEBUG/Worker-7] [chan 0] EOF received (0)
[2016-05-03 05:49:53,632: ERROR/Worker-7] general.send_command() stderr: [u'mount: /media/floppy1: mount failed: Unknown error -1\n']

- /usr/local/src/containers/application/volumes/log/application_1/media/:/media/floppy1
```

In my Dockerfile:

```
RUN mkdir -p /media/floppy1
VOLUME ["/media/floppy1"]
```

This [link](https://serverfault.com/questions/672611/is-it-possible-to-mount-a-host-directory-as-a-volume-on-a-running-docker-contain) suggest is not supported.

Answer (score 1):

In my docker-compose I added:

`privileged: true` setting.

Comment: Worked for me as well. Running with docker run --privileged fixes the problem.